# How to make formula field for salesforce field?

Tags: if-statement, salesforce, crm

I am trying to make formula field for the salesforce field. the condition is given below.

```
if Company = "WIL" And (ShippingCountry = "United States" Or "USA") then
   "US"
elseif Company = "WST" And (ShippingCountry = "United States" Or "US") then
   "USA"
elseif ShippingCountry <> "" then
   ShippingCountry
elseif Company = "WIL" then
   "US"
elseif Company = "WST" then
   "USA"
else
   ""
end if
```

Comment: Could you please provide more detail? What issues are you facing? If the field editor prompted an error, please add it to the post.

Comment: @ RubenDG  I am working with Salesforce crm. I m create new formula field for account object and this is the condition to using for making formula field

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The trailheads are always a good start. I would suggest [Use Formula Fields](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/point_click_business_logic/formula_fields) and [Advanced Formulas](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/modules/advanced_formulas).
The documentation pages about [Formula Operators and Functions](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=customize_functions.htm&type=5) might be useful too.

Keep in mind that you must use fields API Names, not labels, so it's `Company__c`.
If `Company__c` is not a picklist field:

```
IF( AND(Company__c = 'WIL', OR(ShippingCountry = 'United States', ShippingCountry = 'USA')),
    'US',
    IF( AND(Company__c = 'WST', OR(ShippingCountry = 'United States', ShippingCountry = 'US')),
        'USA',
        IF( NOT( ISBLANK(ShippingCountry) ),
            ShippingCountry,
            IF( Company__c = 'WIL',
                'US',
                IF(Company__c = 'WST', 'USA', '') 
            ) 
        ) 
    ) 
)
```

If `Company__c` is a picklist field you should use `ISPICKVAL(picklist_field, literal_value)`, so the formula would be:

```
IF( AND( ISPICKVAL(Company__c, 'WIL'), OR(ShippingCountry = 'United States', ShippingCountry = 'USA')),
    'US',
    IF( AND(ISPICKVAL(Company__c, 'WST'), OR(ShippingCountry = 'United States', ShippingCountry = 'US')),
        'USA',
        IF( NOT( ISBLANK(ShippingCountry) ),
            ShippingCountry,
            IF( ISPICKVAL(Company__c, 'WIL'),
                'US',
                IF( ISPICKVAL(Company__c, 'WST'), 'USA', '') 
            ) 
        ) 
    ) 
)
```